# Which parameters can I use to analyse my cipher?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptanalysis

I have made a new methodology for a symmetric key cryptography in which I have used matrix operations, a boolean function and ASCII conversion. Please suggest me the possible parameters to judge my algorithm.

Comment: ASCII conversion is usually not considered part of a modern cipher (unless is it explicitly made for human consumption). Modern ciphers convert octet strings (binary data) to octet strings. The conversion to and from the octet string is not considered part of the cipher.

Comment: Start with a Ph.D. in math with specialization in cryptography.  When you're done, you will know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

> Now please suggest me the possible parameters to judge my algorithm.

The most important parameters at the current development stage of your algorithm are probably:

- your understanding of other algorithms
- your ability to break other algorithms, or at least to fully understand how others manage to break them
- your knowledge of number theory
- your relationship with recognized experts in the field of cryptography

If you really have the necessary knowledge to create a new algorithm then you would not need to ask here for the important parameters to judge it. If you algorithm is good enough than you will manage to get a recognized expert to look at it. If you don't know any of the experts then I doubt that you will be able to create a good algorithm.

I also recommend to look at [the nice analysis of some other homemade algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24729/what-are-the-vulnerabilities-of-this-homemade-encryption-algorithm) just to get a feeling for how easy it is to get things wrong.